# CSS: How to get an animated gif background-image on top of a div

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a loading overlay thing.
Currently, I have some javascript adding and removing the class that makes everything 45% opaque, and adds the mac-like spinner for waiting until (sorting for example) complete.

Now, the current way,

```
.currently-loading {
opacity:0.45;
-moz-opacity:0.45;
filter:alpha(opacity=45);
width: 950px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(../images/loading.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}
```

puts the image on top, but the gif doesn't animate.
Without the background-attachment: fixed, it animates, but text can be on top of the loading gif.

ideas?

Comment: Would be easier to answer if you included your html, I think.

Comment: the HTML is just a table that can change width and height. reason why I want to do it with a background image, is because it's easy.  the width, heigh, positions are already there... the width and height are also variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it not an option to do this with an `img` tag?

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay"><img src="loading.gif" alt="Be patient..." /></div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay img { display: none; }

#overlay.currently-loading img { 
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;
    heigth: 100%;
}
```

---

Updated css.

Comment: reason why I want to do it with a background image, is because it's easy.  the width, heigh, positions are already there... the width and height are also variable.

Comment: @DerNalia: You could just set the width and height properties of the image to 100%, and it would still stretch to be the same properties as its container. See my update...

Answer (score 2):

hmm.. maybe you can try absolute positioning instead, something like this :

```
HTML
<div class="mydiv">
    <div class="text">Currently Loading....</div>
    <div class="currently-loading">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

CSS
.currently-loading {
    opacity:0.45;
    -moz-opacity:0.45;
    filter:alpha(opacity=45);
    background-image: url(../images/loading.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    height:48px;
    width:48px;
    z-index:10;
}
.text { display:block; width:200px; height:100px; position:absolute; font-weight:bold; z-index:20;}
```