# want to show wait gif while changing image source through jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code by which I am changing main image on click of thumbnails

```
$(".thumb").click(function() {
    $("#mainimage").attr("src", $(this).attr("alt"));
});
```

I want to show wait gif while the news image loads.
thanks

Comment: you can place one before you start image load and remove it afterwards.

Comment: will you please show me the code, I will be obliged.

Comment: create `<img id = "wait" style = "display:none;">` and code in `$(".thumb").click(function() { $("#wait").toggle() /*code here*/ $("#wait").toggle() });`

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight: It will not work as images are loaded asynchronously, check my answer below.

Comment: @KhanhTO not sure what that means but w/e

Comment: Have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905468/jquery-progressbar-on-changing-image-attrsrc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). This event is fired when the image has finished loading, you could hide your loading gif in this event handler

```
$("#mainimage").load(function(){
   //Hide your wait gif
});
```

Show your loading gif before setting the `src`

```
$(".thumb").click(function() {
    //show your wait gif
    $("#mainimage").attr("src", $(this).attr("alt"));
});
```

***Update:***
This would not work if the image is cached and the event won't trigger.

> Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

A simple workaround is appending a random string to prevent caching

```
$(".thumb").click(function() {
        //show your wait gif
        $("#mainimage").attr("src", $(this).attr("alt") + "?" + Math.random());
    });
```

This may have performance hit, but it works

Comment: I think you want, `$("body").on("load", "#mainimage", function() { ... });` since the src is changing which will trigger another `.load()` event for that element.

Comment: @Solomon Closson: thanks for the suggestion, this is also an option using delegated event to deal with dynamically generated elements.

Comment: What I'm trying to say, is that this will not work after the initial image loads.  When you change the src value of the image, it will not trigger `.load()` again.  I don't even think delegated event will work either.  You will most likely have to create a new image object and than it should work.

Comment: @techansaari: I guess the problem is browser cache, when you reload an image from the cache, the event won't trigger.

Comment: Then if the image is loaded from the cache, there will certainly be no need to display the loading gif.

Comment: @techansaari : check my updated answer with a simple solution to prevent caching.